# Python Variable Creating Function

Tags: python, function, variables

I use this set of code very frequently so I created a function and I wanted to use it instead of writing the code multiple times.

```
def setVar():
 try:
   x = int(input())
 except:
   print("The number is not an integer please try again")
   setVar()
```

The function is as follows:

```
def setVarInt(x):
 try:
    x = int(input())
 except:
    print("The number you have entered is not an integer.")
    print("Please try again.")
    setVarInt(x)
```

So when I do setVarInt(T) I want it to create a variable T and wait for an input.

Input Format:

```
setVarInt(T)
print(T)
```

Output Format:

```
13  #This is where I input T
13
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Computer Coding\Python\My Code\Function Files\setVars.py", line 19, in <module>
setVarInt(T)
NameError: name 'T' is not defined
```

Comment: It looks like you just need to return the value if it's an int.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: `return x` to return it

Comment: As others mentioned, in order to get what you want, you need to return a value, but the reason you're getting the error is that T isn't defined when you pass it to your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use recursion to solve this problem, you should be using a `while` loop. Also, your `x` parameter isn't needed.

```
def setVarInt():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input())
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter an integer')
```

And then when you call this function, you have to catch the return value in order to print it.

```
x = setVarInt()
print(x)
```

Comment: Also probably worth pointing out that you should just catch `ValueError` vs. all exceptions. [You could just `return int(input())` without the else block]

Comment: I'd also rename the function from `setVarInt` to `getInt`, as it really isn't setting a variable. The `setVar` is a leftover of the OPs confusion.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what i needed it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You've done it almost right. You have just forgotten `return` key word.

Try this:

```
def setVar():
    try:
        x = int(input())
        return x
    except:
        print("The number is not an integer please try again")
        return setVar()



x = setVar()
print(x)
```

Comment: Unless you `return setVar()` in the exception it will not return anything if they don't enter an int the first time. And probably worth making this a loop vs recursive.